# Send email through SendGrid API with Dynamic Template not working

Tags: c#, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I'm using the C# library for send email with the dynamic template that i'm created. 
The code that I used I copied from [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#with-mail-helper-class).

When I executed the code I recived the status code that was `Accepted` (like I'm showing in the image that I post)
[image]

but the problem is that the email is not reaching my inbox, and in my SendGrid Dashboard UI the email doesn't appear (is not showing that the email was accepted, or blocked, etc)

In the other hand, if I use the following code, the email is delivered normally and it is in my inbox

```
var client = new SendGridClient(Options.SendGridKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress(email, "Sistema"),
                Subject = asunto,
                //PlainTextContent = message,
                HtmlContent = message,
            };

            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

            // Disable click tracking.
            // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
            msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

            await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Any help?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with different `from` and `to` email addresses.

Below code working fine for me since a while.

```
    var client = new SendGridClient(Options.SendGridKey);
    var from = new EmailAddress("from@test.com", "Name");
    var to = new EmailAddress("to@test.com");
    var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleTemplateEmail(from, to, templateId, dynamicTemplateData);
    await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Comment: The code works for me. I had to create another account in SendGrid. I tried your suggestion and it works